# CNN: Forwarding batch of images - Stuck when using multiple kernels

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network

I'm putting it first, I'm not using any frameworks and I started learning Convolutional layers like last week. I understand the basics of forward propagation, haven't even touched back but that's out of scope. Here's my confusion:

Suppose I have 4 images, with 3 channels of size 4x4: 4x3x4x4
And I have kernels with 3 channels of size 3x3: K*3x3x3

I'm trying to compute the convolutions on all 4 images but I always get lost in the dimensionality. Here's what I've tried:

```
import numpy as np


w = np.array(
    [
        # Img: 1, 4x4 image with 3 channels
        [
            [
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1]
            ],
            [
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0]
            ],
            [
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2]
            ]
        ],
        # Img: 2, 4x4 image with 3 channels
        [
            [
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0]
            ],
            [
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1]
            ],
            [
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2]
            ]
        ],
        # Img: 3, 4x4 image with 3 channels
        [
            [
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2]
            ],
            [
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0]
            ],
            [
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1]
            ]
        ],
        # Img: 4, 4x4 image with 3 channels
        [
            [
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2]
            ],
            [
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1]
            ],
            [
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0]
            ]
        ]
    ]
)

f = np.array(
    [
        # Filter: 1, 3x3 filter for 3 channels -> All 1s
        [
            [
                [1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1]
            ],
            [
                [1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1]
            ],
            [
                [1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1]
            ]
        ],
        # Filter: 2, 3x3 filter for 3 channels -> All 2s
        [
            [
                [2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2]
            ],
            [
                [2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2]
            ],
            [
                [2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2]
            ]
        ]
    ]
)

hori_dimension = (w.shape[3] - f.shape[3]) // 1 + 1
vert_dimension = (w.shape[2] - f.shape[2]) // 1 + 1
r = np.zeros(shape=(w.shape[0], f.shape[0], vert_dimension, hori_dimension))
for i in range(vert_dimension):
    for j in range(hori_dimension):
        r[:, :, i, j] += np.sum(w[:, :, i:i+3, j:j+3] * f, axis=(1, 2, 3))
print(r)
```

This doesn't work and I have problems with this part, when I have K number of kernels for N number of images.

If I have a single kernel however, then I can define my operation as (This works flawlessly):

```
hori_dimension = (w.shape[3] - f.shape[3]) // 1 + 1
vert_dimension = (w.shape[2] - f.shape[2]) // 1 + 1
r = np.zeros(shape=(w.shape[0], vert_dimension, hori_dimension))
for i in range(vert_dimension):
    for j in range(hori_dimension):
        r[:, i, j] += np.sum(w[:, :, i:i+3, j:j+3] * f, axis=(1, 2, 3))
print(r)
```

which results in 2x2 feature for each image:

```
[[[27. 27.]
  [27. 27.]]

 [[27. 27.]
  [27. 27.]]

 [[27. 27.]
  [27. 27.]]

 [[27. 27.]
  [27. 27.]]]
```

This seems right, I have 1 kernel so I'll have 1 feature map for each image, yielding 4 feature maps of 2 dimensions. In the above I would expect, another dimension. Having 4 feature maps for each kernel, but I can't figure this one out.

@Update:

This seems like doing the job:

```
p = 0
s = 1
number_of_input_images, number_of_image_channels, height_of_image, width_of_image = w.shape
number_of_kernels, number_of_kernel_channels, height_of_kernel, width_of_kernel = f.shape
assert(number_of_image_channels == number_of_kernel_channels)

width_of_features = (width_of_image - width_of_kernel + 2*p) // s + 1
height_of_features = (height_of_image - height_of_kernel + 2*p) // s + 1
feature_maps = np.zeros(shape=(number_of_input_images, number_of_kernels, height_of_features, width_of_features))

for k in range(f.shape[0]):
    for i in range(height_of_features):
        for j in range(width_of_features):
            feature_maps[:, k, i, j] += np.sum(w[:, :, i:i+3, j:j+3] * f[k], axis=(1, 2, 3))

print(feature_maps)
```

It results in the following feature maps:

```
[
    # pic1
    [
        # kernel1
        [
            [27. 27.]
            [27. 27.]
        ]
        # kernel2
        [
            [54. 54.]
            [54. 54.]
        ]
    ]
    # pic2
    [
        #kernel1
        [
            [27. 27.]
            [27. 27.]
        ]
        #kernel2
        [
            [54. 54.]
            [54. 54.]
        ]
    ]
    #pic3
    [
        #kernel1
        [
            [27. 27.]
            [27. 27.]
        ]
        #kernel2
        [
            [54. 54.]
            [54. 54.]
        ]
    ]
    #pic4
    [
        #kernel1
        [
            [27. 27.]
            [27. 27.]
        ]
        #kerbel2
        [
            [54. 54.]
            [54. 54.]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is there a better way of doing it?  Is this even correct? To me it seems fine. Having a picture and multiple kernels, the result of convolution will be the feature map from each kernel put "after" another right? So having K amount of kernels where the feature maps has N*N dimensions the output of the convolutional layer becomes K*N*N. In that way, the above seems right, I guess? As I said I truly have messed up with these N dimensions...

@Update:

I ended up with the following code for valid(forward)/full(backprop) convolutions:

```
def convolve(sources: np.ndarray,
             kernels: np.ndarray,
             mode: str = 'valid',
             padding: typing.Tuple[int] = (0, 0),
             stride: int = 1):
    number_of_input_images, number_of_image_channels, height_of_image, width_of_image = sources.shape
    number_of_kernels, number_of_kernel_channels, height_of_kernel, width_of_kernel = kernels.shape
    assert(number_of_image_channels == number_of_kernel_channels)

    if mode == 'full':
        padding = (height_of_kernel, width_of_kernel)

    if padding:
        sources = np.pad(sources,
                         ((0, 0), (0, 0), (padding[0], padding[0]), (padding[1], padding[1])),
                         mode='constant', constant_values=0)

    kernels = np.rot90(kernels, k=2, axes=(2, 3))

    width_of_features = (width_of_image - width_of_kernel + 2*padding[1]) // stride + 1
    height_of_features = (height_of_image - height_of_kernel + 2*padding[0]) // stride + 1
    feature_maps = np.zeros(shape=(number_of_input_images, number_of_kernels, height_of_features, width_of_features))

    for k in range(f.shape[0]):
        for i in range(height_of_features):
            for j in range(width_of_features):
                feature_maps[:, k, i, j] = np.einsum('ncij,cij', sources[:, :, i:i+3, j:j+3],  kernels[k])

    return feature_maps
```

Any feedback would be appreciated. I read that the kernels must be rotated when doing the convolution so I rotate twice by 90 degrees, also has the ability to use custom padding, and in order to have a full convolution I pad with the size of the kernel -1 so that all surrounding elements are zero and I get no index errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with the following piece of code to handle the the batch convolution:

```
def convolve(input_images, kernels, padding=0, stride=1):
    number_of_images, image_height, image_width, image_channels = input_images.shape
    number_of_kernels, kernel_height, kernel_width, kernel_depth = kernels.shape
    assert (image_channels == kernel_depth)

    input_images = np.pad(input_images, ((0, 0), (padding, padding), (padding, padding), (0, 0)),
                          mode='constant', constant_values=(0,))
    kernels = np.rot90(kernel, k=2, axes=(1, 2))

    fm_height = (image_height - kernel_height + 2*padding) // stride + 1
    fm_width = (image_width - kernel_width + 2*padding) // stride + 1
    feature_maps = np.zeros(shape=(number_of_images, fm_height, fm_width, number_of_kernels))
    for n in range(number_of_images):
        for i in range(fm_height):
            for j in range(fm_width):
                x = input_images[n, i * stride:i * stride + kernel_height, j * stride:j * stride + kernel_width, :]
                feature_maps[n, i, j, :] = np.einsum('ijk,mijk', x, kernels)
    return feature_maps
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at one image and one kernel at a time. If your image is of size `wxh` and your kernel is of size `f*f` and if you stride(s) one pixel at a time and if you pad your iamge with `p` pixels then then after convolution of 1 image with 1 kernel will result in a image of size `(w-f+2*p)/s + 1, (h-f+2*p)/s +1)`. In your case `w=h=4`, `f=3`, `s=1` and `p=0`.

1. First you take a `f*f` patch from the image. Since you have 3 channels each patch will be of 3 channels
2. The kernels each channel is multiplied with the respective channel in the patch (element wise multiplication)
3. Finally all the number in all the channels are summed up to produce one single number.

#### Pictorial representation

[image]

Multiple such patches are created by striding over the images, and since each patch creates a single number with the kernel, you end up with a matrix of number for all the patches form the image.

This is done for each image, and so you end up with a smaller convolved image for each image.

### Code sample

```
images = np.ones((2,3,4,4))
kernal = np.ones((3,3,3))
w = 4
f = 3
p = 0
s = 1
r = np.ones((2, 
        int((w-f+2*p)/s +1), int((w-f+2*p)/s +1)))
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    for h in range((4//3)+1):
        for w in range((4//3)+1):            
            x = np.sum(image[:, w:w+3,h:h+3]*kernal)
            r[i,w,h] = x
print (r)
```

Output:

```
[[[27. 27.]
  [27. 27.]]

 [[27. 27.]
  [27. 27.]]]
```

2 images of size `4x4` convolved with kernel of size `3x3` will give you 2 images of size `2x2` (verify `(4-3+0/1 +1, 4-3+0/1 +1)`)

Must read resource : [CV231n](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I successfully imeplemented this part but for me I have 4 images with 4 2x2 feature maps. My problems come, when I have multiple kernels as I get lost even on paper. The first sample code is for 2 kernels, and that doesn't work. The 2nd case is with a single kernel just like you show here, that works. Updated the formatting of my question now it should become clear where my issue lies. So this part, is done. I also read the linked article along with a couple others and now trying to understand the derivation process.

Comment: For single kernel you will get single convolved image and for n kernels you will get n convolved image. Is your issue with the implementation ?

Comment: Yeah, my issue is with the implementation. My first code sample has my attempt in implementing it, where the resulting feature map has the dimensions of: (Number.of.images x Number.of.kernels x W x H).